# Not able to fetch the value of a key from JSON data

Tags: json, typescript, protractor

I am trying to fetch value if "id" from JSON response I got from a POST request.

```
{
"callId": "87e90efd-eefb-456a-b77e-9cce2ed6e837",
"commandId": "NONE",
"content": [
    {
        "scenarioId": "SCENARIO-1",
        "Channel": "Channel1-1",
        "data": {
            "section": {
                "class": {
                    "repository": [
                        {
                            "export": "export-1",
                            "modules": "module-1",
                            "index": "23",
                            "period": {
                                "axis": {
                                    "new_channel": "channel-1.1"
                                },
                                "points": [
                                    {
                                        "id": "6a5474cf-1a24-4e28-b9c7-6b570443df9c",
                                        "duration": "150",
                                        "v": 1.01,
                                        "isNegligible": false
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
}
```

I am able to display the entire response json and am also able to get the value of "callId" using below code. Getting error at last line:

```
Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

Code snippet:

```
function callback(error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    let responseData = JSON.stringify(body);
    //Display the entire response
    console.log(responseData);
    //Display the callId
    console.log(body['callId']);
    //Getting error here
    console.log(body.content[0].repository[0].points[0].id);
  }
}
```

Any solution to get value of "id" ?

Comment: Hi Praveen, shouldn't it be `body.content[0].data.section.class.repository[0].period.points[0].id` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now you are trying to log `body.content[0].repository[0].points[0].id)`.

If you look at it carefully the `repository[0]` is an object and it has no immediate child points.

So `repository[0].points` would evaluate to undefined and by specifying `repository[0].points[0]`, you are trying to access property 0 of undefined as the error states.
The correct way of accessing `id` would be as follows :

```
body.content[0].data.section.class.repository[0].period.points[0].id
```

If you have confusion regarding parsing JSON try breaking it down by consoling `body` and then by expanding it in the console or in JSONeditor

PS: It is also recommended that you check at each level if the value exists before trying to access a deeper child elements, since in some cases your `body` may not contain one of the values, say content for example. In that case trying to access `body.content[0]` will cause an error. So it is recommended to do checks at each level like follows

```
if(body){
    if(body.content){
        if(body.content[0]){
            /* and so on*/
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Chris. Now i undrstood how to parse json. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
console.log(body.content[0].data.section.class.repository[0].period.points[0].id)
```

Comment: My json nodes will change (based on the request json) for each of my test scenarios. Is there any way to directly get "id" from response? Otherwise I will have to form and maintain these paths for each of the scenarios.

Comment: If your node change, it can be quite hard to easily find your id. If you know there will always be one array, you could keep you response as string, and use a regex to match the id and its value. It will not work if you have multiple id in your nodes. You can try to recursively search in your jsons nodes but you will keep the same problem (id must be unique). I don't know what you want to do, but if you could use ''callId'' as id it would be easier for you.

Comment: I cant use callId. Have to use 'Id' only. May be I can try with regex as you suggested. Need to see how much I can achieve. Thanks for your answer rm4.